# LDAP AD - range attribute, how to use it?

Tags: ldap

I'm trying to use the range attribute.

For testing, I use a search that without range return 3 entries, and I set the range to 0-1, which should return only the first 2. However, I get all 3 results.

This is how I do it:

```
String rangeStr = attribute + ";range=0-1";
String returnedAttrs[] = {rangeStr, attribute};
_searchControls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAttrs);
_searchControls.setSearchScope(scope);
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = _context.search(name, filter, _searchControls);
List<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();
while (answer != null && answer.hasMoreElements())
{
    Attribute currentAttr = answer.next().getAttributes().get(attribute);
    if (currentAttr == null)
        continue;
    for (int i=0; i<currentAttr.size(); i++)
    {
        String val = currentAttr.get(i).toString();
        result.add(val);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I use page size of 1000, but if I understand correctly, that is not supposed to influence the ranged search (given that the page size is larger than the requested range). Is that correct?

Comment: Is this still a problem for you?

Comment: If you have an answer I will be very glad to read it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't yet but I didn't want to spend time on it if it wasn't.  :-)  What framework are you using to access AD?

Comment: I access it via java code, which runs on unix machine.

Comment: What is 'scope' initialised to?  And, for that matter, 'name' and 'filter'?

Comment: scope, name and filter are all received from the user. So they can be any legal value. scope is either SearchControls.OBJECT_SCOPE, SearchControls.ONELEVEL_SCOPE or SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE. name is any base DN (should have chosen a better name for this variable), and filter is, well, a search filter.

Comment: The 'range' should not be used in new code. The syntax (which is active-directory specific) violates the LDAP standard for attributes, and that alone is reason enough to eschew it. This is a case of Microsoft treating standards as if they were guidelines instead of rules and results in confusion, difficulty of migrating code, and poor programming practices.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. So, is there another way to set the range?

Answer (score 8):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import ldap

def msad_flatten_ranges(conn, dn, ldap_dict):
  for attrname in ldap_dict:
    if ';range=' in attrname:
      #
      # parse range attr
      #
      actual_attrname, range_stmt = attrname.split(';')
      bound_lower, bound_upper = [
        int(x) for x in range_stmt.split('=')[1].split('-')
      ]

      step = bound_upper - bound_lower + 1
      while True:
        attr_next = '%s;range=%d-%d' % (
          actual_attrname, bound_lower, bound_upper
        )

        dn, attrs = conn.search_s(
          dn, ldap.SCOPE_BASE, attrlist = [attr_next])[0]

        assert len(attrs) == 1

        ret_attrname = attrs.keys()[0]

        ldap_dict[actual_attrname].extend(attrs[ret_attrname])
        if ret_attrname.endswith('-*'):
          break

        bound_lower = bound_upper + 1
        bound_upper += step
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation yet to comment on Russell's post, but I had to tweak his answer a tiny bit to work under python3 + ldap 3.3.1.   (But thanks, Russell, for your initial solution.)

First, I wrapped his function with another to cycle through the results from my previous search:

```
  for result in results:
      dn, obj = result

      msad_flatten_ranges(conn dn, obj)
```

(sorry, I know that's almost too obvious - I'm adding it for the newbies.)

I then modified his function:

```
def msad_flatten_ranges(conn, dn, ldap_dict):
  ranged_attrs = [ attrib for attrib in ldap_dict if ';range=' in attrib ]

  for attrname in ranged_attrs:
    #
    # parse range attr
    #
    actual_attrname, range_stmt = attrname.split(';')

    ldap_dict[actual_attrname] = ldap_dict.pop(attrname)

    bound_lower, bound_upper = [ 
      int(x) for x in range_stmt.split('=')[1].split('-')
    ]

    step = bound_upper - bound_lower + 1

    while True:
      bound_lower = bound_upper + 1
      bound_upper += step

      attr_next = '%s;range=%d-%d' % (
        actual_attrname, bound_lower, bound_upper
      )

      dn, attrs = conn.search_s(
        dn, ldap.SCOPE_BASE, attrlist = [attr_next])[0]

      assert len(attrs) == 1

      ret_attrname = tuple(attrs.keys())[0]

      ldap_dict[actual_attrname].extend(attrs[ret_attrname])
      if ret_attrname.endswith('-*'):
        break
```

The changes were as follows:

1. I pre-determined the attributes in need of expansion (ranged_attrs) because I didn't want any changes to ldap_dict keys to break the outer loop.
2. I converted the existing (initial) range to being the actual_attrname entry so as to avoid re-fetching the same range again (see the line with ldap_dict.pop(attrname)) which solved the need to have that dict key exist already as the later "extend" call was broken for me.  And the "pop" removes the ranged version of the key,value.
3. I then moved the the shift of the bound_lower and bound_upper to the front of the loop since I already had the initial range.
4. I cast attr.keys() to be a tuple so that it could be indexed into.  As it was, that was failing.